# Bushing and Shaft Alignment

Tags: mechanical-engineering, tolerance

I"m working on a design and having difficulty calculating possible misalignment.

I have a shaft (diameter D, tolerance t) that is running through two bushings. The two bushings are separated by a distance L. The two bushings are of width W1 and W2 (measured along the axis parallel to the shaft), with internal diameter of D1 and D2 with tolerances of T1 and T2. (see image below)

[image]

How do I go about calculating the potential misalignment of the shaft? When I started this I though it was going to be a quick 5 minute challenge but the more I work on it the more difficult it's seeming.

Comment: How are the bushings seated, are they in some kind of tube or machined cavity. The alignment of the bushings can only be as good as the accuracy of the method of generating their relative positions, obviously ;-)

Comment: The bushings are press fit into a tube using a hydraulic press, both simultaneously with the same insertion system. Their mounting 'depth' and the concentricity of their OD to the mounting tube is assumed to be perfect for what I'm working on right now. Obviously that's overly optimistic, but, I'm reasonably sure that the dimensions on what I listed is more critical to my alignment mainly given the tolerances I'm working with. I'll be working on THAT problem next after I nail this one down.

Comment: Let me be bold and suggest a new foolproof way of building the assembly. Instead of press fitting the bushings into the tube, get a bushing that will slip fit into the tube with shaft inside both bushings to align themselves perfectly and use Loctite bearing retaining compound to secure the bushings into the host tube. When the Loctite cures, just slide the shaft out. Now the bushings will be perfectly aligned with each other. Finis.

Comment: The assembly method is a good idea, however the tolerance stack up is still the primary question. I'm trying to calculate how much alignment I can expect given manufacturability tolerances  of the bushings and the shaft. location and concentricity of the bushings to the outer tube isn't really a concern at this point. Also, just as an aside for the application adhesives are VERY not preferable due to the fact that they require a curing time, whereas  a press fit operation can be done faster in a single step.

Comment: OK then , if you have to have a press fit then you can basically eliminate the tolerance stack up concern by selecting standard size shafts and bushings with standard tolerances guaranteed by the manufacturers and just ream out the bushings with a reamer that you will select by trial and error until the shaft slips into the assembly. You will  want to ream both bushings with one shot so you will have to fixture this operation on a milling machine or drill press.

Comment: As a humorous aside(hopefully), remember the three cardinal laws of engineering. 1  If you want it to be good , it cant be fast and cheap. 2 If you want it to be cheap , it cant be fast and good. 3  If you want it to be fast , it cant be cheap and good.

Comment: Ok, you're still missing the point I'm not asking how to get around calculating this. I'm asking how to calculate a tolerance stack up in this case. Standard sized shafts still have tolerances that need to be calculated reaming the bushing is fine but you still have to calculate the stack up to determine the misalignment of the shaft. Not solving the problem and saying it's too hard, too expensive or too time consuming isn't a solution.

Comment: Ok, the only way to calculate the tolerance stack up is to build some assemblies and measure ( from a large enough sample distribution) what works, given parts tolerances that you source from your supplier(s). TRIAL AND ERROR !

Comment: That's not a tolerance stack up. A tolerance stack up is calculated by taking your nominal dimensions and determining what alignments are possible given the specified tolerances  on your drawings. I.e. given the manufactueability of the parts and what can be adhered to. Given the max and min dimensions possible of all parts, the final assembly has a max and min possible alignment  as a function of clearance and tolerances of all parts in an assembly. Tolerance analysis is not a trial and error process it should be a prerequisite for building a precision part.

Comment: The assembly I'm working on is a legacy system which didn't have proper analysis documentation. I need to know the stack up of the system so that the new system I'm designing to replace it is at minimum as accurate as the legacy system. By doing a tolerance analysis before building it you can prove mathematically how well it will work.

Comment: Then why are you asking the question here, how can you expect us to give you an answer if you yourself have no documentation for the legacy system. And with all due respect, don't take this the wrong way, but if you think you can design something on paper that works perfectly in the real world without doing some real working models, the "real world of engineering " awaits you, good luck !

Comment: The reason I'm asking the question here is because I'm trying to fill in the missing documentation. I'm not trying to design something perfectly on paper, i'm trying to solve an engineering problem. A tolerance stackup problem. This is a very common type of analysis in the "real world of engineering". Of course a prototype is required, but that still doesn't negate the problem of SOLVING the stackup problem, which is done and required before justifying building a prototype.

Comment: OK , one last time and then I'm through trying to help you, no more comments from me:  you can't even begin to do this stack up problem until you know the displacement from the axial center line of your bushings, until you press fit many bushings and do many measurements to get the average displacement, you are dead in the water as far as a real mathematical analysis is concerned.

Comment: A tolerance stack up is based entirely on the specd dimensions. The bushings are X plus minus t the shaft is y plus minus t2.. these are dimensions that the manufacturer is held to. You do not require built parts to do a tolerance  stack up. A tolerance stack up is completed before you build anything. It is a theoretical range. It is the question I am asking about. It is a mathematical problem, and requires nothing be built. A tolerance stack up is calculated to determine what the best and worst cases can be of your assembly based on the tolerances you can build to.

Comment: Tolerance analysis is the foundation of GD&T

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I would like to point out that your CAD application can most likely do this for you. Just make a parametric drawing and sweep the values you need. This may be more practical as you go forward since the cad application can effortlessly make changes based on geometric constraints and you don't need to calculate this.

[image]

**Image 1**: Parametric sweep of one value. No harder than typing 3 values. Note the drawing s intentionally exaggerated.

Making the sweep by script is not much harder. This opens up statistical analysis by montecarlo simulation. Doing it this way reduces chance of error made during the mathematical analysis. Of course, this is both a good thing and a bad thing. Analytical analysis can give insights into global minima, but as the complexity of your analysis grows this might not be feasible so a local minima may suffice.

But yeah you can calculate this by hand too, the problem is that one you start adding the things you now consider trivial this may no longer be a trivial extension.

[image]

**Image 2**: Vector expression

You can express this as a equation of vector expressions

$$
  \vec a + \vec b + \vec c = 0
$$

where $\vec a$ is known, magnitude of $\vec b$ is known and direction of $\vec c$ is linked to vector  $\vec b$. So vector  $\vec b$ is $D \cdot \{sin(\theta), cos(\theta)\}$ therefore  $\vec c$ is $x \cdot\{-cos(\theta), sin(\theta)\}$. Since you have 2 directions and 2 unknowns this is solvable. But i wont take this further.

Comment: Thanks! I've built a rough resolution table based on cad, very similar to the method you've mentioned. I've been trying to solve the problem analytically though which is where I've gotten stuck at. I like having the equations for my stack ups in areas specifically so that you can show danger zones with tolerance outliers. Brute forcing the problem will work it just takes more time.

Comment: @Diesel what computer algebra system do you use? Mathematica, Mathcad, Sympy??

Comment: I've been doing all algebra by hand. Python (Sympy) would be my go to though. I've tried a few symbolic solvers on this problem but I've ended up with horrendous systems, I was hoping for a second set of eyes on the problem that might find a more elegant solution.

Comment: The 'best' solution I've come up with is to solve the problem from both sides (i.e. solve for theta), one unknown, two equations and then iterate for a matched solution. It's not what I was hoping for but seems to be the most useful. And, easy enough to automate when solving the vector loop for the total stack-up.

Comment: @Diesel [Newton-Raphson](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Newton%27s_method) root finding?

Comment: Nothing that fancy, just brute force iteration. My range is small enough that it converges to within an acceptable error fairly quickly.

Comment: @Diesel newton raphson isnt very fancy. But yes i agree that if you know the range a binary search will do